# How do I focus a specific window with applescript without doing an activate and bringing other windows to the front?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm looking for a method w/ AppleScript to select/focus a specific window of an application without actually doing an "activate" which brings **all** windows to the front.

Here's what I have so far:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set windowTitle to title of first window whose title contains "whatever"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
    click menu item windowTitle of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
end tell
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
```

The problem is the "activate" in the last line. That brings everything to the front, but I just want the one window.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're right that the `activate` command raises all windows. The `open` shell command only raises one window though:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set index of window 1 where title contains "whatever" to 1
delay 0.05
do shell script "open -a Google\\ Chrome"
```

Comment: Ah, this is great. It comes close, unfortunately, if Chrome is already focused the "whatever" window only flashes to the front and the currently focused window wins out. If I use the "click menu item" technique along w/ the open -a, it seems to work, but that requires accessibility. Any ideas to get around that?

Comment: Just adding a "delay 0.05" in between your two lines seems to work perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, but you could also try `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome" to perform action "AXRaise" of window 1`.

Comment: Strange how no one on SO would check here... anyway, I cited this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34375804/8047

Comment: I'm getting: `execution error: The variable title is not defined. (-2753)`

Comment: Re: execution error. Change `title` to `name`.

Comment: In my case, this script causes all Google Chrome windows to be brought up in front of other applications. Is that by design?

Comment: I'm getting: `Can’t set index of window 1 whose name contains "Calendar" to 1.`

Comment: How is it that using 'title' works for some people and 'name' for others? Is it because of different versions of macOS?