# Watch folder for Photos

Tags: icloud, photos.app

When I'm on my iPhone, pictures downloaded from the Internet are automatically uploaded to my iCloud Photo Library.

I want the same thing to happen for pictures downloaded from the Internet when I'm on my Mac. Let's say I want to upload to the Icloud Photo Library every new image in the folder Downloads.

Is there a way to do it seamlessly ?

Comment: Both of those should be relatively easy to account for in AppleScript. Bring a window to the front: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117421/ Checking a box would require a bit more work, but you would need to know how exactly the window presents itself.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add Photos actions to Automator using https://photosautomation.com/
2. Construct the following Folder Action in Automator
   [image]

I'm still not 100% satisfied, since folder actions are not super robust so I welcome other answers!